# ERROR in ./src/components/Main.jsx - Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

May somebody help me please? When I try to use webpack, it shows me this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /path/to/my/folder/src/components/Main.jsx: Unexpected token (170:13)
  168 |ReactDOM.render(
  169 |<TodoApp
> 170 |    todos={...store.getState()}
      |              ^
  171 |     />,
  172 |     document.getElementById('app')
  173 |   );
```

And this is configuration of my webpack.config.js:

```
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel',
        query : {
          presets : ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

May somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In JSX, `{}` is a javascript *expression*. Since you are trying to pass an *object literal*, you need to use double braces:

```
todos={{...store.getState()}}
```

[JSX Expression Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions)

As david points out below, if your intention is just to assign the state to `todos` without adding any properties of your own, this will suffice:

```
todos={store.getState()}
```

Comment: Isn't `todos={{...store.getState()}}` the same as `todos={store.getState()}`? You could also do `<TodoApp {...store.getState()} />` if you wanted the top-level props of your state tree to be the props of the component.